# I want to install nodejs and testacular with my own nuget package. How can i do that?

Tags: installation, nuget, karma-runner

I have to create a nuget package that installs Testacular in client machine. Testacular need node.js to be installed. So ineed that to be installed already.

How can i include them in my nuspec file.

Thank you for reading...help me if you can

Answer (score 0):

Checkout www.chocolatey.org and their ecosystem. This does the same (and I believe there's even a package for NodeJS on there)